# I'm getting a "this.container is undefined" error when using mat-paginator

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table that has a list of users called from a database using a spring REST API which works perfectly but when I wanted to add a paginator to help go through the whole list of users I started getting a "this.container is undefined" error when trying to click on the paginator.

Also, for some reason It showing "Items per page: 5" only even though I have almost 27 users.

Here's my html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter" style="width: 500px !important">
</mat-form-field>
        <mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="id" class=".mat-column-id">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.id}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="username" class=".mat-column-username">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.username}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="email" class=".mat-column-email">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="duration-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.email}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname" class=".mat-column-name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>firstname</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="duration-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.firstName}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname"class=".mat-column-name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="duration-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.lastName}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="enabled" class=".mat-column-enabled">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Enabled</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="duration-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.enabled}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="registeredDate" class=".mat-column-date">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Registered Date</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell class="duration-cell" *matCellDef="let user">{{user.registeredDate | date: shortDate}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row class="mat-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="onRowClicked(row)"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

and the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { NewDialogComponent } from '../new-dialog/new-dialog.component';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.scss', './dashboard.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  loginuser: any = {};
  imgSrc: any = {};
  users: any[] = [];
  imageToShow: any;
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'registeredDate', 'enabled'];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private service: UserService, private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.loginuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   this.service.getAllUsers(this.loginuser.token).subscribe(u => {
   this.dataSource.data = u as User[];
   this.users = u;
  // console.log('user: ', this.users);
   });
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
   if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
   this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of this injected member variable is not immediately available at component construction time!

Angular will fill in this property automatically, but only later in the component lifecycle, after the view initialization is completed.

If we want to write component initialization code that uses the references injected by **@ViewChild**, we need to do it inside the **AfterViewInit lifecycle hook**.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {        
      @ViewChild(SomeComponent)
      someComponent: SomeComponent;

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('Values on ngAfterViewInit():');
        console.log("someComponent:", this.someComponent);
      }  


    }
```

In Your case just put these two line in NgAfterViewInit LifeCyle as:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { NewDialogComponent } from '../new-dialog/new-dialog.component';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.scss', './dashboard.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  loginuser: any = {};
  imgSrc: any = {};
  users: any[] = [];
  imageToShow: any;
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'registeredDate', 'enabled'];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private service: UserService, private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.loginuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   this.service.getAllUsers(this.loginuser.token).subscribe(u => {
   this.dataSource.data = u as User[];
   this.users = u;
  // console.log('user: ', this.users);
   });
 ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }  

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much but It only solved half the problem. Now, I can go between the pages with the left and right arrows but I still can't choose the number of users per page

Comment: Try with these options
<mat-paginator
              *ngIf="totalLength != 0"
              [length]="totalLength"
              (page)="pageChange($event)"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
            ></mat-paginator>

Comment: and what should I write in the ts file?

Comment: in [length], total length of users array and in pageSize , how many records you want to display and (page) event is used to detect any change in table and, [showFirstLastButtons] is used to jump 1st or last page.

Comment: So I shouldn't change anything in the ts component?

Comment: No. Just Write like and for pageSize, you have to define pageSize and you can change that on pageChangeEvent.
<mat-paginator *ngIf="users.length != 0" [length]="users.length" (page)="pageChange($event)" [pageSize]="pageSize" [showFirstLastButtons]="true" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" ></mat-paginator>

Comment: Hi there, I hope you're still around but I'm getting the same problem with mat-dialog. Can you help me?
I've created a button that would open a dialog containing a user info but whenever I click it I get this erro: 'ERROR TypeError: "this.container is undefined" '